# Special Character Closing tag issue in SOAP UI

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I am using below request in SOAP UI. One of the parameter has '&' part of string value due to which closing tag gets disappeared. Any solution for that?

```
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ns:SvcConsumer>XYZ</ns:SvcConsumer>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ns:SvcPassword>"SL&3IHO76$F*43=hjk"</ns:SvcPassword>
    <!--Optional:-->
```

The **SvcPassword tag** in above request gets disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either escape the & as & or put it in a CDATA block as follows

```
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:SvcConsumer>XYZ</ns:SvcConsumer>
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:SvcPassword><![CDATA["SL&3IHO76$F*43=hjk"]]></ns:SvcPassword>
```

Comment: Got it.. can be solved using &amp; or using CDATA. thanks for the help